# Microsoft Project 2016 add-in (Javascript) Check if Project 2016

Tags: javascript, ms-project, office-addins

Is there a way to check if Microsoft Project is 2016? I want to run a check on whether it is or not, and then navigate to a page based on the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neat ways to get environment (i.e. Office version)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840459/neat-ways-to-get-environment-i-e-office-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at Michael Zlatkovsky's answer on : [Neat ways to get environment (i.e. Office version)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32851938/126912).

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, Microsoft