# Office Add-In Development - Malformed GET URL (_host_Info=...)

Tags: java, tomcat, ms-office, office-js

I am currently developing a MS Word Office Addin using the JavaScript interface provided by Microsoft. I made a test implementation using a Django backend, where everything worked fine.

However for the final product I have to integrate functionality with an existing Java Backend that runs in multiple configurations, which are out of my control. Consisting of Vaadin for the UI and mostly Tomcat (but not always) as a Servlet Container.

I've run into the problem that the IFrame that runs inside Word, appends an unwanted and malformed _host_info to the request URL, that contains un-urlencoded pipe characters.
e.g: Tomcat Log:

```
"GET /myapp/?_host_Info=Word|Win32|16.01|en-US HTTP/1.1" 200 2101
```

This malformed URL produces the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid location URI received from client.
... full stack trace at bottom of the post...
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index          45: https://localhost:8443/myapp/?_host_Info=Word|Win32|16.01|en-US
```

As far as I know, I have no control, on whether or not to append this Parameter to the URL, since in the Manifest File of the Addin I only specify the source URL like below, and the info gets added automatically.

```
<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:8443/myapp/ " />
```

Checking the [Documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) I didn't find this behaviour in there, so i might be missing something. Querying the host info is mentioned in [this](http://simonjaeger.com/here-i-am-detecting-the-office-host-in-excel-and-word-add-ins/) blog post, but it seems it should not be part of the URL.

- Is there a way I can stop the Office Add-In from appending: 
  **?_host_Info=Word|Win32|16.01|en-US HTTP/1.1** to the request?
- If not, is there a correct way to filte/ignore that part of the URL with Tomcat? Since the whole app has been running correctly with my Apache Webserver & Django Backend, where the URL was received too, but it worked.

As for question two, I've already tried to implement a Servlet filter that should remove the parameter in question. But since it relies on the same Java library to parse the URL to look at it, the same exception is thrown.

```
> May 23, 2016 11:04:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyUIServlet] in context with path [/word-to-moxis] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid location URI received from client] with root cause
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index h(invalidated link because of 10 reputation / two links allowed policy)ttps://localhost:8443/myapp/?_host_Info=Word|Win32|16.01|en-US
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3111)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at com.vaadin.server.Page.init(Page.java:651)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:679)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.`UIInitHandler`.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
```

*Update:*

The following Quick & Dirty Hack acts as a workaround of the problem. Still baffled as to why they chose to encode the information that way:

```
public class AddinServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap;

    public AddinServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest originalRequest) {
        super(originalRequest);
        parameterMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>(originalRequest.getParameterMap());
        parameterMap.remove("_host_Info");
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {
        // TODO: Improve
        String[] value = parameterMap.get(name);
        if (value == null || value.length == 0)
            return null;
        if(name == "v-loc"){
            return value[0].replace('|', '_');
        }

        return value[0];
    }
}
```

*Update 2/ Feb17:*

With more recent Tomcat updates the workaround above no longer suffices. As noted in the comments, the versions **7.0.73**, **8.0.39**, **8.5.7** have a stricter URL policy. Therefore there is no solution to use the versions of tomcat for hosting office add-ins without additional tooling. I really hope this situation changes soon because such a small, probably useless string can use such problems with deployments.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: 
The API is now available for use:

console.log(Office.context.host); //example: Excel

console.log(Office.context.platform); //example: PC, MAC, IOS, null (for stand alone website)

Possible values for host are:
Word
Excel
PowerPoint
Outlook
OneNote
Project
Access

Possible values for platform are:
PC
OfficeOnline
Mac
iOS
Android
Universal

---

We recently removed the query parameters from the URL in light of the issues noted in single page applications. the _host_info_ is no longer appended for add-ins opened in the browser (Office Online).

@Matthias: For this issue, adding `office-js` tag would be more accurate. I couldn't append given the size limit for tags.

Comment: Hi @Sudhi, _host_Info still appears in Office365's Outlook. As for Feb 12 2017 we face with it in Outlook for Web and Windows. Microsoft Support Team (617021492952666) told it's not possible to disable it and proposed to find a workaround here. 
Since Apache Tomcat 7.0.73 such URLs treated as a [insecure](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-6816) and rejected by the server at very low level (valve or filter not possible).
I glad to read that you removed this query parameter. But when we could expect it in Office365 and then in on-premise installations and Exchange server?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sudhi. I changed the tags of the post. As for your change with Office Online - do you have any plans to port this change to the desktop versions of Office? It would be very appreciated since its a major annoyance. We've run into the same problem @Peter describes - our Add-in stops working when updated to more recent tomcat versions.

Comment: I am having the same issue. As for Feb 13 2018 I face it in Outlook for Web. I think this extra query parameter _host_info will become wider issues. I am connecting my apps to Dropbox service using Dropbox oauth flow from Outlook Web Add-ins. And Dropbox responses this extra query parameter as Bad Request, so there is no way for me to connect to Dropbox service in Outlook Web Add-ins.

Comment: I'll check and get back if the pipe symbol could be avoided. If not, will it work if we escaped it to make URL safe? Or is it that Tomcat web server doesn't like the pipe separator regardless.

Comment: Hi @Sudhi. Thank you for your reply and the API changes. I totally missed the notifications for this thread. I can confirm this works in all recent versions of Office.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an apache with mod_rewrite enabled in front of your tomcat, it's possible to add this dirty apache rule to infly reencode the outlook request :

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)_host_Info=(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)
> RewriteRule ^(.*) "$1?%1_host_Info=%2\%7c%3\%7c%4\%7c%5\%7c%6\%7c%7" [QSD,PT]
> ```

I hope this can help

Comment: Thanks for the tip! At the moment using apache or nginx, seems to be the only fix if one has to use newer Tomcat Versions.

Comment: Yes sure.

BTW, it's also possible to avoid the rewrite condition using mod_jk and the ajp connector on tomcat as it's not impacted by the fix done for [CVE-2016-6816](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2016/q4/503).

Comment: Thanks again, always great to have multiple options.

Answer (score 1):

This change of the URL also wreaks havoc in Angular if you are playing with the urlRouteProvider at all.  It appears to create a digest loop because it is location changing event to fire inside Angular which exceeds the 10 loop limit of the digest. :(

Comment: Sorry for the late response! That sucks, i hope you found a solution in the meantime. I managed to find the correct Servlet Filter Parameter to filter out, and now it integrates well with Vaadin. Still...an annoyance. I've edited my post with my workaround.

Comment: Yes, solution was to go back to Microsoft and tell them they should not be altering the URL in such a manner that causes a digest loop in Angular!  Apparently they are working or have already released a patch. :)

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem to this one.

Our solution was to downgrade our tomcat versión from 8.0.39 to 8.0.30.

Look also this: [|' in query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053653/tomcat-8-is-not-able-to-handle-get-request-with-in-query-parameters)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15947259)

Comment: @xlm Actually it *does* provide an answer to this question. Maybe a short one, maybe poorly described, but it does provide an answer.