# Tomcat 8 is not able to handle get request with '|' in query parameters?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat8.5

I am using Tomcat 8. In one case I need to handle external request coming from external source where the request has a parameters where it is separated by `|`.

Request is looks like this:

`http://localhost:8080/app/handleResponse?msg=name|id|`

In this case I am getting following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:467)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:667)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT 1**

It works with Apache Tomcat 8.0.30 but not with Tomcat 8.5

Comment: OK, I guess you'll have to escape it

Comment: Have you took a look into the referenced RFC?

Comment: RFCs are meant to be improved.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This behavior is introduced in all major Tomcat releases:

- Tomcat **7.0.73**, **8.0.39**, **8.5.7**

To fix, do one of the following:

- set `relaxedQueryChars` to allow this character
  (recommended, [see Lincoln's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212677/2757140))
- set `requestTargetAllow` option
  (deprecated in Tomcat 8.5) ([see Jérémie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005213/2757140)).
- you can downgrade to one of older versions (not recommended - security)

---

Based on [changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html), those changes could affect this behavior:

Tomcat 8.5.3:

> Ensure that requests with HTTP method names that are not tokens (as required by RFC 7231) are rejected with a 400 response

Tomcat 8.5.7:

> Add additional checks for valid characters to the HTTP request line parsing so invalid request lines are rejected sooner.

---

*The best option (following the standard)* - you want to encode your URL on client:

```
encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/app/handleResponse?msg=name|id|")
> http://localhost:8080/app/handleResponse?msg=name%7Cid%7C
```

or just query string:

```
encodeURIComponent("msg=name|id|")
> msg%3Dname%7Cid%7C
```

It will secure you from other problematic characters ([list of invalid URI characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500078/2757140)).

Comment: Thanks, I just downgraded my ``apache-tomcat-8.5.11`` to ``apache-tomcat-8.0.30`` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @BhuwanGautam I would not recommend downgrading tomcat as latest tomcat versions have all the necessary CVE patches which might have affected your downgraded versions already. Encoding URI parameters would be a fix - or using `relaxedQueryChars` - In long term, anywhere in code that uses reserved RFC 3986 chars should be refactored.

Comment: It seems `relaxedQueryChars ` is still hackable only. Is there any proper solution provided by Apache?

Comment: For me "encodeURIComponent" worked like a charm! Tnx for describing alternative fixes.

Comment: is there any properties file change in spring boot case?

Answer (score 54):

Since Tomcat **7.0.76**, **8.0.42**, **8.5.12** you can define property [`requestTargetAllow`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html) to allow forbiden characters.

Add this line in your `catalina.properties`

```
tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}
```

Comment: From tomcat 8.5 onwards # WARNING: Using this option may expose the server to CVE-2016-6816
#tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|

Answer (score 18):

The parameter `tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow` is deprecated since Tomcat 8.5: [tomcat official doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html).

You can use `relaxedQueryChars / relaxedPathChars` in the connectors definition to allow these chars: [tomcat official doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html).

Comment: In 8.5 I tried these and it didn't have any effect. The best option is to always encode your urls.

Answer (score 18):

Issue:
Tomcat (7.0.88) is throwing below exception which leads to 400 – Bad Request.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. 
The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986.
```

This issue is occurring most of the tomcat versions from 7.0.88 onwards.

Solution: (Suggested by Apache team):

Tomcat increased their security and no longer allows raw square brackets in the query string. In the request we have [,] (Square brackets) so the request is not processed by the server.

Add `relaxedQueryChars` attribute under  tag under server.xml (%TOMCAT_HOME%/conf):

```
<Connector port="80" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="150"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443"
           compression="on"
           compressionMinSize="2048"
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"
                                     relaxedQueryChars="[,]"
             />
```

If application needs more special characters that are not supported by tomcat by default, then add those special characters in `relaxedQueryChars` attribute, comma-separated as above.

Comment: Works for me latest tomcat 8 for DHIS2 ,because this helps some one !!!

Answer (score 7):

The URI is encoded as UTF-8, but Tomcat is decoding them as ISO-8859-1. You need to edit the connector settings in the server.xml and add the URIEncoding="UTF-8" attribute.

or edit this parameter on your application.properties

server.tomcat.uri-encoding=utf-8

Comment: URIEncoding attribute on the <Connector> element in server.xml to something specific (e.g. URIEncoding="UTF-8") (https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding)

Comment: @hwak your link is down

Comment: found similar link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding

Answer (score 5):

Escape it.  The pipe symbol is one that has been handled differently over time and between browsers.  For instance, Chrome and Firefox convert a URL with pipe differently when copy/paste them.  However, the most compatible, and necessary with Tomcat 8.5 it seems, is to escape it:

http://localhost:8080/app/handleResponse?msg=name%7Cid%7C

Answer (score 4):

Adding "relaxedQueryChars" attribute to the server.xml worked for me :

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"/>
```

Comment: how to allow # in the url ? relaxedQueryChars="^{}|[]_#" and im using tomcat 8.5.27

Comment: Try : &#35;
So Maybe something like this :
relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;&#35;"