# Tomcat 8 is not able to handle get request

Tags: java, tomcat8

I am using Tomcat 8. In one case I need to handle external request coming from external source

Tomcat doesnot log the request.
In this case I am getting following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:467)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:667)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to ask If there is any way I can turn the logging to see which character is causing this issue? Also If I log the request Header, which field in header causes this issue.

I read the thread [Tomcat 8 is not able to handle get request with '|' in query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053653/tomcat-8-is-not-able-to-handle-get-request-with-in-query-parameters)

but adding "tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}"
didnt work.

Comment: Did you also try to escape them?

Comment: Is the invalid character you're dealing with actually one of `|{}`?  I don't know how that solution would help otherwise.  If it is not one of those characters, you'll need to follow the other solution recommendations.

Comment: I am trying to identify the the invalid character. Dont know how should I log it. I tried other solution like changing the server.tomcat.uri-encoding=utf-8 It did not work.

Comment: @tsolakp How can I escape it ?