# Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986 error on GET request with tomcat 9.0.7

Tags: javascript, maven, struts2, tomcat9

I am using **Apache Tomcat/9.0.7**. I requested to an external source as below.

```js
var loc = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/webpages/PS.jsp?jsonArry="+jsonArry; 
document.getElementById('PSFrame').setAttribute('src', loc);
```

Below I have mentioned the error I got

```html
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:460)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:291)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I had read [similer problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053653/tomcat-8-is-not-able-to-handle-get-request-with-in-query-parameters). But still couldn't resolve

Comment: I'm confused; you're just wedging an object's default string conversion into a URL? You need to stringify and URL-encode it.

Comment: I'll do it & try again. Anyway, in Apache Tomcat/8.5.5 this is working fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41150474/438992