# "#" in nginx routing path causes tomcat error "Invalid character found in the request target..."

Tags: tomcat, nginx, java-8, tomcat9

I have tomcat running and I'm trying to route to the main app which is `localhost:8080/AppName/#/` through nginx. I am able to reach the url by using `hostname:8080/AppName/#/` but when I use nginx I get `Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986`. This is likely nginx renaming the `#` symbol because using nginx to rout to `localhost:8080/AppName` works without issue, i just need to then go to `hostname/#/` to reach my `localhost:8080/AppName/#/` route.

Thus nginx route:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/AppName/#/;
}
```

**Any idea how to get around this `#` character issue with nginx and/or tomcat (9)?**

The only fix I found didn't work ([Tomcat 8 is not able to handle get request with '|' in query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053653/tomcat-8-is-not-able-to-handle-get-request-with-in-query-parameters/44005213#44005213)) . I also tried directly encoding it as `%23`.

Comment: Anything from the `#` onwards is the [URL fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) and is not sent to the server. It is for the exclusive use of the browser and client-side javascript.

Comment: @RichardSmith are you sure it's a fragment since it's wrapped with `/` on each end? So a url to the login page would be `AppName/#/Login`. The `/#/` exists for every page on the app.

Comment: Your URL `hostname:8080/AppName/#/`, the server at `hostname:8080` will receive an http(s) request line that looks like `GET /AppName/`.

Comment: You're right, looking into it I found http://www.jenitennison.com/2011/03/06/hash-uris.html which suggests that i will be unable to route with the hash on the nginx end. Thank you @RichardSmith

Comment: @RichardSmith , any insights on SEO implications of this by chance? If you know about it at all