# Invalid bracket character in query parameters in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, query-string

For the URL `https://example.com?price[gte]=100` I get the exception

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [?price[gte]=100]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:491) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked related question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053653/tomcat-8-is-not-able-to-handle-get-request-with-in-query-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be configured in properties

```
server:
  tomcat:
    relaxed-query-chars: "[,]"
```