# How to detect device/application using office js

Tags: javascript, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

Office 365 add-in users can access add-ins through the Windows Outlook client, the Mac client, and OWA (android/iphone). Is there a way to identify device/application using office.js?

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect the platform in JavaScript is via the [user agent string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). Here are examples for some of the specific cases you mentioned:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var plat = navigator.platform;
if(ua.match(/iPhone/i)){
    //iPhone device
}
else if(ua.match(/iPad/i){
    //iPad device
}
if(ua.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){
    //Android OS
}
else if(plat.toLowerCase().indexOf("mac") > -1){
    //Mac OS
}
else if(plat.indexOf("Win") > -1){
    //Windows OS
}
```

However, depending on the reason why you want to detect the platform, you may want to use other methods of detecting specific features/functionality instead. The following post covers non-device-related ways to detect environment info, including the "Requirements" model which can check for API capabilities: [Neat ways to get environment (i.e. Office version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840459/neat-ways-to-get-environment-i-e-office-version/32851938#32851938)

Comment: this gives browser and OS details but how do we know app users coming through Outlook Mac/Outlook windows or OWA . cant i use **Office.context.mailbox. diagnostics.hostName**  to detect application?       [http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics)

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about where the request came from, whether it was Outlook for windows/Mac/ web app) you could use the hostname setting from Office.js.
more details [here](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Office.context.diagnostics.platform`

Please see: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.platformtype?view=common-js-preview)