# get excel application version using office.js file

Tags: office-js

I am developing office addin using office.js.
How to get desktop excel application version using office.js, this is required because, we have noticed sometime user has old version of office and not all the latest updates are updated. in that case few of the office.js apis are not working. we want to show minimum version (including build no) required message to customer on office addin taskpane.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer here about checking the Office environment: [Neat ways to get environment (i.e. Office version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840459/neat-ways-to-get-environment-i-e-office-version/32851938#32851938)

In your case since you care about whether particular APIs are available, you should use the `isSetSupported` method in order to decide whether to show your users an error message for each case.

Comment: i think it works. if i check for ExcelApi version 1.2 it says unsupported on old version of office 2016, where latest updates are not installed..is there any relation with "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"  1.1 mentioned in office.js path and excel api version, i was thinking 1.1 in the path is api version, but that was not the case.