# Excel add-in: How to detect whether the host platform is "office online"

Tags: office-js

I am looking for an effective way to detect whether the host platform is "office online". I noticed the online supports CompressedFile api while others don't. Is it a good way to rely on this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840459/neat-ways-to-get-environment-i-e-office-version/32851938#32851938

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same question - I found this page that I think answers it completely:

[Detecting Office Host in Add-Ins](http://simonjaeger.com/where-am-i-detecting-the-office-host-in-office-add-ins/)