# Office JS API - Word version

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to get the MS Word version from the API? I see the version number visible in the UI so I'm guessing it's not hidden from users, but I'm not sure it's accessible through the API.

Also, is it anyhow possible to check, through the API, if the user is using Desktop or Online Word? Despite the API being the same, the experience is not the same on both platforms and knowing the difference would make development a lot easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neat ways to get environment (i.e. Office version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840459/neat-ways-to-get-environment-i-e-office-version)